# C# generic types equality operator

Tags: c#, generics, equality

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

> When applying the where T : class constraint, avoid the == and !=
>   operators on the type parameter because these operators will test for
>   reference identity only, not for value equality. This is the case even
>   if these operators are overloaded in a type that is used as an
>   argument. The following code illustrates this point; the output is
>   false even though the String class overloads the == operator.

```
public static void OpTest<T>(T s, T t) where T : class
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(s == t);
}

static void Main()
{
    string s1 = "target";
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder("target");
    string s2 = sb.ToString();
    OpTest<string>(s1, s2);
}
```

Everything is ok until i tried following, with same method

```
static void Main()
{
    string s1 = "target";
    string s2 = "target";
    OpTest<string>(s1, s2);
}
```

It outputs 'True', s1 and s2 reference different objects in memory even they have same value right? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings are interned in .NET, so when you do

```
string s1 = "target";
string s2 = "target";
```

they are both pointing to the same object. This is why the MSDN example uses a `StringBuilder`, this fools the CLR into creating another string object with the same value so that the operator test in the generic method will return false.

Comment: This is correct. It can be seen at the [MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) , "When two or more string literals that are equivalent according to the string equality operator (Section 7.9.7) appear in the same assembly, these string literals refer to the same string instance."